# Group values in column based on common words

Tags: r, dataframe, group-by, cluster-computing

I have a dataframe:

```
ID    message
1     request body: <?xml version="2.0",<code> dwfkjn34241
2     request body: <?xml version="2.0",<code> jnwg3425
3     request body: <?xml version="2.0", <PlatCode>, <code> qwefn2
4     received an error
5     <MarkCheckMSG>
6     received an error
```

I want to extract groups of values in column based on common words. So, first three rows in message column can be considered as same group, though they are little bit different. Fourth and sixth as members of same groups. How could i group those values i column message using words and structural similarity criterion for that? What is a good method for that? The dataframe in example is given for example. So, im more interested in methods suiting the idea of problem, than regular expressions based solution for example

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps try a k-medoids clustering analysis with a string distance measure?

```
library(cluster)
library(stringdist)

find_medoids <- function(x, k_from, method = "osa", weight = c(d = 1, i = 1, s = 1, t = 1)) {
  diss <- stringdist::stringdistmatrix(x, x, method = method, weight = weight)
  dimnames(diss) <- list(x, x)
  trials <- lapply(
    seq(from = k_from, to = length(unique(x))), 
    function(i) cluster::pam(diss, i, diss = TRUE)
  )
  sel <- which.max(vapply(trials, `[[`, numeric(1L), c("silinfo", "avg.width")))
  trials[[sel]]
}

map_cluster <- function(x, med_obj) {
  unname(med_obj$clustering[x])
}
```

Output

```
> map_cluster(df$message, find_medoids(df$message, 2, "cosine"))
[1] 1 1 1 2 3 2
```

For your real data, you may have to adjust some parameters such as the string distance method (the example above used cosine distance).

Comment: This is a brilliant solution.

Comment: Wow ekoam, awesome methodology.

Comment: i don't really get what result means

Comment: Elements 1-3 (i.e. "request body") belong to group 1; elements 4 & 6 (i.e. "received an error") belong to group 2; element 5 (i.e. "<MarkCheckMSG>") belongs to group 3. @french_fries

Comment: i get result 2 3 1 1 1 1 for this dataframe ID <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6)
message <- c('request body: <?xml version="2.0",<code> dwfkjn34241','request body: <?xml version="2.0",<code> jnwg3425','request body: <?xml version="2.0", <PlatCode>, <code> qwefn2',
             'received an error', '<MarkCheckMSG>', 'received an error')

df <- data.frame(ID, message)

Comment: Please use a **character** vector for this clustering analysis. `df <- data.frame(ID, message, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)` @french_fries